# Parse schema and an import in the same schema

Tags: java, xml, parsing, dom, xml-parsing

Just wondering if there are any ways to parse a xsd file AND an xsd that's imported in the original xsd at the same time, so I can get direct access to the elements in the imported xsd. Are there any frameworks that makes this possible?

Just an example of what I mean

From the XSD that I want to parse:

`<xsd:import namespace="..." schemaLocation="anotherFile.xsd">`

`<xsd:element ref="anElement" />`

From the XSD that's imported in the parsed file

`<xsd:element name="anElement">`
`<xsd:simpleType>`
`<xsd:restriction base="xsd:string">`
 `<xsd:enumeration value="THIS" />`
`<xsd:enumeration value="IS" />`
 `<xsd:enumeration value="THE" />`
`<xsd:enumeration value="ELEMENTS" />`
`<xsd:enumeration value="I" />`
`<xsd:enumeration value="WANT" />`
`<xsd:enumeration value=":-)" />`
`</xsd:restriction>`
`</xsd:simpleType>`
`</xsd:element>`

So, What I want is to get access to the elements in the imported xsd when I'm parsing the original xsd by some kind of inlining or something :-)

Is this possible in some way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you just need to implement a LSResourceResolver class that will able to read from the schema locations you specify:

```
 /**
 * This function validates a DomResult. T
 *
 * @param domResult
 * @param schemaFile path to the schmea file to validate against.
 * @throws org.xml.sax.SAXException
 * @throws java.io.IOException
 *
 */
protected void validateDomResult(DOMResult domResult, String schemaFile) throws SAXException, IOException, Exception {

    Schema schema = createSchema(schemaFile);
    javax.xml.validation.Validator validator = schema.newValidator();
    ErrorHandler mySchemaErrorHandler = new LoggingErrorHandler();
    validator.setErrorHandler(mySchemaErrorHandler);
    DOMSource domSource = new DOMSource(domResult.getNode());
    validator.validate(domSource);
    if (((LoggingErrorHandler) mySchemaErrorHandler).isError()) {
        throw new Exception("Validation Error");
    }
}

/**
 *
 * @param baseSchemaFilePath
 * @return
 * @throws java.lang.Exception
 *
 */
protected Schema createSchema(String baseSchemaFilePath) throws Exception {

    SchemaFactory factory = SchemaFactory.newInstance(XMLConstants.W3C_XML_SCHEMA_NS_URI);
    LSResourceResolver resourceResolver = (LSResourceResolver) new LocalSchemaLSResourceResolver();
    factory.setResourceResolver(resourceResolver);
    Schema schema = factory.newSchema(new File(baseSchemaFilePath));

    return schema;
}
```

Here is a simple LSResourceResolver implementation that  looks for schemas in an xsd directory on the class path:

```
public class LocalSchemaLSResourceResolver implements LSResourceResolver{

    protected final Log logger = LogFactory.getLog(getClass());

    public LSInput resolveResource(String type, String namespaceURI, String publicId, String systemId, String baseURI) {

        LSInput input = new DOMInputImpl();
        try {
            FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(new File("classpath:xsd/" + systemId));

            input.setByteStream(fis);
            return input;
        } catch (FileNotFoundException ex) {
            logger.error("File Not found", ex);
            return null;
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for great answer. I solved this by using xson, Xml Schema Object Model. It has great support fr schema.

Answer (score 1):

It look like you need JAXB to get your schema (including imported schema) into Java classes.

Comment: JAXB would probably work, but it does not fit this task because the parsing has to be done dynamically.

Answer (score 1):

This works for me when the XSD files are either on local /src/main/resources directory or packed in a jar:

```
final SchemaFactory sf = SchemaFactory.newInstance(XMLConstants.W3C_XML_SCHEMA_NS_URI); 
final URL url = this.getClass().getClassLoader().getResource("META-INF/parent.xsd");
final Schema schema = sf.newSchema(url);
```

parent.xsd has included "kid.xsd" -- both XSD files are under the same directory